# handling multiple types of arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have multiple dynamic text boxes.

```
<input type="text" name="Paid_Amount[]">
<input type="text" name="Charges_Type[]">
```

Each text box value have multiple rows (installments) in database.
Paid Amount should be divided according to number of installments.
for example i have development charges = `50,000`
and then installments if development charges

```
Installment table
---------------------------------------------------------------
ID   Charges_Type             Installment_Amount    Paid_Amout      
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    Land Cost                10000                   0                
2    Land Cost                10000                   0            
3    Land Cost                10000                   0             
4    Land Cost                10000                   0          
5    Land Cost                10000                   0
6    Development Charges      5000                    0
7    Development Charges      5000                    0
```

I need to set Paid amount (getting from `<form>`) to installment table's paid amount

the requirement is: if i set `12,000` in land cost then `10000` should be set in first installment and remaining `2000` will be set in next installment

i have tried with `foreach` and `do while` loop but getting confused with multiple arrays:

```
$Charges_Type = $this->input->post('Charges_Type'); // array
$Paid_Amount = $this->input->post('Paid_Amount'); // array
$result = array of rows from installment table
```

how to handle these `3 arrays`:

```
$merge = array_merge($Paid_Amount, $result);
    foreach ($merge as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if(!empty($merge[$key]))
                        {
                            foreach($result as $in)
                            {
                                if($in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
                                {
                                    $i = 0;
                                    do 
                                    {
                                        if($in['Installment_Amount'] >= $value && $in['Paid_Amount'] == 0 && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
                                        {
                                            echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$value."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." AND `Charges_Type` = '".$key."''";
                                            $value = $value - $in['Installment_Amount'];
                                        }
                                        if($in['Installment_Amount'] < $value && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
                                        {
                                            echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$in['Installment_Amount']."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." AND `Charges_Type` = '".$key."''";
                                            $value = $value - $in['Installment_Amount'];                        
                                        }
                                        if($i['Paid_Amount'] != 0 && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
                                        {
                                            $value = $value + $i['Paid_Amount'];
                                            echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$value."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." '";
                                            $value = 0;
                                        }   
                                        $i++;
                                    } 
                                    while ($value > 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }       
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't provided an answer to your question, but an alternative way of writing your code to make it easier to read by refactoring it. That makes it easier when working with multiple array loops.

I noticed in your table, Installment table, you have a misspelling, Paid_Amout, I'm not sure if that's just a misspelling when you posted it or if it's an error in your SQL. But that could lead to issues.

```
$merge = array_merge($Paid_Amount, $result);
foreach ($merge as $key => $value)
{
    if(empty($merge[$key]))
        continue;

    foreach($result as $in)
    {
        if($in['Charges_Type'] != $key)
            continue;

        $i = 0;
        do 
        {
            if($in['Installment_Amount'] >= $value && $in['Paid_Amount'] == 0 && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
            {
                echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$value."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." AND `Charges_Type` = '".$key."''";
                $value = $value - $in['Installment_Amount'];
            }
            if($in['Installment_Amount'] < $value && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
            {
                echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$in['Installment_Amount']."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." AND `Charges_Type` = '".$key."''";
                $value = $value - $in['Installment_Amount'];                        
            }
            if($i['Paid_Amount'] != 0 && $in['Charges_Type'] == $key)
            {
                $value = $value + $i['Paid_Amount'];
                echo "UPDATE `tbl_installment` SET `Paid_Amount` = '".$value."', `Paid_Date` = '".$Paid_Date."', `Is_Paid` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '".$in['ID']." '";
                $value = 0;
            }   
            $i++;
        } while ($value > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no spelling mistake..
you missed the 3rd array.. i have to update the records where land cost = land cost
development charges = development charges

Comment: I didn't add or remove any arrays. I edited the code to make it easier to read. Where does $result come from?

Comment: yes i know but i am telling you just for information. i have 3 arrays 
1. amount 
2. charges type (land cost, development charges etc)
3. query array (records from table)


$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_installment` WHERE `Plot_ID` = '".$plot_id."' AND `Paid_Amount` < `Installment_Amount` AND `Is_Active` = '0'");

$result = $query->result_array();